# Symfony sfThumbnail Plugin with 5 Simultaneous Uploads

Tags: image, symfony1, upload, thumbnails

I have a product form that users can upload 5 pictures simultaneously.  Everything is working fine with that but I'm trying to implement the sfThumbnail plugin so that it creates a thumbnail of each of the pictures at the same time.   The code below works for Picture1 but Picture2, 3, 4, and 5 it doesn't.   I've tried messing with the code and I can't get it to work with each file individually.   It just takes the uploaded file for Picture2 for example and it names it the same as picture 1.   So when it runs through I end up with 5 uploaded pictures, but only 1 thumbnail with the filename of the first picture.

I tried to duplicate the code 5 times and customize it for each of the pictures but I got the same result.

If there's a more efficient way of doing this please show me.  This is just what I got from the plugin documentation.   Thanks

```
if($this->isModified())
    {
      $uploadDir = sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir');
      $thumbnail = new sfThumbnail(150, 150);
      $thumbnail->loadFile($uploadDir.'/car/'.$this->getPicture1());
      $thumbnail->save($uploadDir.'/car/thumbnail/'. $this->getPicture1());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
if($this->isModified())
    {
      $uploadDir = sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir');
      $thumbnail = new sfThumbnail(150, 150);
      if($this->getPicture1())
      {
        $thumbnail->loadFile($uploadDir.'/car/'.$this->getPicture1());
        $thumbnail->save($uploadDir.'/car/thumbnail/'. $this->getPicture1());
      }

      if($this->getPicture2())
      {
        $thumbnail->loadFile($uploadDir.'/car/'.$this->getPicture2());
        $thumbnail->save($uploadDir.'/car/thumbnail/'. $this->getPicture2());
      }

.. the rest of my the pictures
    }
```

Comment: You can put each picture name (`array('picture1', 'picture2', ...)`) in an array and loop on it.

Comment: Hey j0k.   This code seemed to work fine until someone tries to only upload less than 5 pictures.   Each picture that is left at null errors out.   I tried doing an if statement "if($this->getPicture1() <> 'NULL')" but it still throws up the error.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: You should not check if it's null but maybe kind of empty like: `if(strlen($this->getPicture1()))` or directly `if($this->getPicture1())`

Comment: As always, you're right on the money.  I have updated my answer with my updated code.   Thanks again.  :)

Answer (score 0):

For first delete your function:

```
if($this->isModified())
    {
      $uploadDir = sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir');
      $thumbnail = new sfThumbnail(150, 150);
      $thumbnail->loadFile($uploadDir.'/car/'.$this->getPicture1());
      $thumbnail->save($uploadDir.'/car/thumbnail/'. $this->getPicture1());
    }
```

And in your form class insert this function:

```
protected function processUploadedFile($field, $filename = null, $values = null) {

          // prendo il file che è stato caricato
          $fn = parent::processUploadedFile( $field, $filename, $values );

          // se il file esiste ed
          if ( $fn != "" ) {

               try {

                  // array multidimensionale di tutte le tipologie di thumb esistenti
                  $thumbnails[] = array( 'dir' => 'ico',           'width' => 75,      'height' => 75 );
                  $thumbnails[] = array( 'dir' => 'small',      'width' => 150, 'height' => 150 );
                  $thumbnails[] = array( 'dir' => 'medium',      'width' => 400, 'height' => 400 );
                  $thumbnails[] = array( 'dir' => 'big',           'width' => 800, 'height' => 800 );

                  foreach ( $thumbnails as $thumbParam )
                  {
                    $currentFile = sfConfig::get( 'sf_upload_dir' ).'/destination_folder/'.$thumbParam[ 'dir' ].'/'. $fn;
                    if ( is_file( $currentFile ) ) unlink( $currentFile );
                  }

                  foreach ( $thumbnails as $thumbParam )
                  {
                      $thumbnail = new sfThumbnail( $thumbParam[ 'width' ], $thumbParam[ 'height' ], true, false );
                      $thumbnail->loadFile( sfConfig::get( 'sf_upload_dir' )."/destination_folder/original/".$fn );
                      $thumbnail->save( sfConfig::get( 'sf_upload_dir' ).'/destination_folder/'.$thumbParam[ 'dir' ].'/'.$fn, 'image/jpeg' );
                  }

               } catch( Exception $e ) {

               }
          }

          return $fn;
     }
```

Where:
 - the `$thumbnails[]` array contains all the folders you need, with theri dimensions, so all the thumbs you need
 - you need before to create the `destination_folder` folder in your web/uploads directory

Also remember to call the command

```
php symfony project:permissions
```

This function takes all the files in your form, and generate as many thumbs as you need

Comment: The [snippet](http://snippets.symfony-project.org/snippet/337) from this code source doesn't answer the question at all ... (unless you customize it)